# Wordpress menu item alignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hey so our menu is meant to be float:right and the container around it has some more room on the right where the items are meant to line up. For some reason it's not going all the way over though. Kinda looks like a margin or another element is in the way but I can't see anything.

http://perennial.net.au

I'm referring to the top menu before you scroll down. I can see this in firefox and edge but not chrome

```
container_inner{
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header_inner_right{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

I don't see why there would be any space to the right of .header_inner_right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it. Those floats can be a pain

I tested on chrome and firefox

```
  .header_inner_right{
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        clear: right;
    }
```